# Composite component with action attribute conditional validation check throws ClassCastException during restore view phase

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, action, composite-component

I have a JSF composite component(Name Panel). In that component I am using customValidator like below:

```
<h:inputHidden id="nameValidator" value="true">
    <f:validator validatorId="NameValidator"
                            disabled="#{!cc.attrs.nameRequired}" />
    <f:attribute name="firstName" value="firstName" />
    <f:attribute name="lastName" value="lastName" />
</h:inputHidden>
```

`firstName` and `lastName` are two input text on this JSF form. And `nameRequired` attribute is being passed from the place where we are placing this composite component.

I am using this composite component like below:

```
<util:NamePanel viewbean="#{BACKING_BEAN}"
    nameDTO="#{BACKING_BEAN.nameDTO}"
    nameRequired="#{param['requireValidation']=='1' " />
```

On my screen I have two buttons. But I want to validate name only press of Save  button and want to skip the validation on press of Cancel button. For that I have applied conditional validation.

```
<h:commandButton value="Cancel"
        action="#{BACKING_BEAN.doCancel}">
    <f:param name="requireValidation" value="0"></f:param>
</h:commandButton>

<h:commandButton value="Save"
        action="#{BACKING_BEAN.doSave}">
    <f:param name="requireValidation" value="1"></f:param>
</h:commandButton>
```

So when I press the Save button. The Name is getting validated by calling that custom validator but after that when the JSF restore view phase try to restore the page after saving data in database it's throwing below error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error restoring component: nameValidator
       at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.DefaultFaceletsStateManagementStrategy.restoreStateFromMap(DefaultFaceletsStateManagementStrategy.java:518)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: package.NameValidator incompatible with javax.faces.component.StateHolder
       at javax.faces.component._DeltaList.restoreState(_DeltaList.java:222)
       at javax.faces.component.UIInput.restoreState(UIInput.java:1047)
```

But when I replaced `nameRequired="#{param['requireValidation']=='1'"` with `nameRequired="true"` at the place where I am placing composite component in my form, it worked perfectly fine.

Can't understand the reason of it and not able to find a fix for this issue. Or some other way to achieve this.